# How to make input$action starts from zero every time I click on Action Buttom in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

As this link says about Action Button, the  `input$action` return the number of clicks
On the button.
[enter link description here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widget-gallery.html)

**My question is:**

- How can I, after x-clicks, store the x value in a data frame and make the button starts from zero(actually make input$action starts from zero) and after y-clicks store the y value on this same dataframe and on on and on…?

In other words:

I click 3 times , the `input$action` sends me the value 3, I store this value, and starts again(**somehow, I need to make `input$action` come back to zero**), clicking 8 times the input$action sends me the value 8 I store again e keeps going….

Answer (score 2):

It may be simpler to not use the value of the `actionButton` directly and just record the number of clicks between events in an external `reactiveValues` object. This for example has two buttons, one to increase the value and another to add the final value to a vector and reset the counter:

```r
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("action", label = "Action"),
  actionButton("store", label = "Store"),
  
  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(2, verbatimTextOutput("value")))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  values <- reactiveValues(curr = 0,
                         out = integer())
  
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    values$curr = values$curr + 1
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$store, {
    values$out <- c(values$out, isolate(values$curr))
    values$curr <- 0
  })
  
  output$value <- renderPrint({
    values$out
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Nice, can you edit to auto store and print at 3, 8 or show intermediate count so user can keep track of count, without having to store an unwanted count?

Answer (score 2):

If we really need to "reset" the button, we can re-render it. Here is an example app:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("action"),
  actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
  verbatimTextOutput("values")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$action <- renderUI({
    actionButton("action_but", "Action")
  })

  vals <- reactiveVal(tibble(clicks = integer(0)))
  counter <- reactiveVal(0)

  observe({
    counter(input$action_but)
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset,
    {
      vals(add_row(vals(), clicks = as.integer(input$action_but)))

      output$action <- renderUI({
        actionButton("action_but", "Action")
      })

      counter(input$action_but)
    },
    ignoreInit = TRUE
  )

  output$values <- renderPrint({
    list(counter(), vals())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `input$button` is read only, so you can't reset the `input$button` increment without resetting the entire app, which would cause you to lose your saved values. Alternatively, you can keep a copy of the values and reset the count on your copy.

Not sure what you want to do with the reset, but you can still count the number of button presses between your steps, 3, 8 etc. So 8 button presses from 3 would be at `input$button == 11`.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Copy the line below to make an action button
  actionButton("action", label = "Action"),
  
  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(2, verbatimTextOutput("value")),
           column(6, verbatimTextOutput("countOutput")))
  
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # You can access the value of the widget with input$action, e.g.
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$action })
  
  df <- reactiveValues(three = NULL, eight = NULL, thirteen = NULL)
  
  observe({
  
    presses <- c(3, 8, 16)
      
    if(is.null(input$action)){
      
    } else if(input$action == presses[1] & is.null(df$three)) { 
           
        df$three = input$action
     
    } else if(input$action == presses[2]  & is.null(df$eight)){
      
      df$eight = input$action - presses[1]
      
    } else if(input$action == presses[3] & is.null(df$thirteen)) {
      
      df$thirteen = input$action - presses[2]
 }
    
  })
  
  output$countOutput <- renderPrint({
    
    paste(df$three[1], df$eight[1], df$thirteen[1])
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]